# cygpath doesn't convert Windows path correctly

Tags: cygwin, cygpath

**command line shell**

```
echo %PIG_HOME%
C:\cygwin\usr\lib\pig
```

**cygwin**

```
echo $PIG_HOME
C:\cygwin\usr\lib\pig

echo $( cygpath -u "$PIG_HOME" )
/usr/lib/pig

cd $( cygpath -u "$PIG_HOME" )
-bash: cd: /usr/lib/pig: No such file or directory
```

**Question:** why is `cygpath` not converting it to `/cygdrive/c/cygwin/usr/lib/pig`?

**UPDATE:**

The path to the `pig` folder is correct.

**command line shell**

```
C:\Users\john.doe> cd %PIG_HOME%
C:\cygwin\usr\lib\pig>
```

**cygwin**

```
john.doe@COMPUTER ~
$ cd /cygdrive/c/cygwin/usr/lib/pig/

john.doe@COMPUTER /cygdrive/c/cygwin/usr/lib/pig
$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Cygwin,

```
C:\cygwin\lib\pig = /usr/lib/pig
```

and

```
C:\cygwin\usr\lib\pig = /cygdrive/c/cygwin/usr/lib/pig
```

This setup is by design.

The `C:\cygwin\usr\lib` folder is not created by any packages and should not be created by you either.

Answer (score 0):

Type `mount` in your terminal window.

My `c:\cygwin\bin` and `c:\cygwin\lib\` are mounted at `/usr/bin` and `/usr/lib` respectively. I suspect that your `c:\cygwin\usr\lib` is mounted at `/usr/lib`.

Therefore, the "unix" path to `c:\cygwin\usr\lib\pig` would be `/usr/lib/pig`.

Comment: Indeed, it is the case. So how am I supposed to work with Windows paths using cygpath if cygwin cannot understand the path that cygpath outputs? Is it not the purpose of cygpath to make Windows paths readable for cygwin?

Comment: In my case, the /usr/lib/pig will actually find the file in cygwin. Does it not in your case?

Comment: As Steven Penny mentionned, `C:\cygwin\usr\lib` should not be created because of the ambiguous structure of the mount: `/usr/lib\pig` would then point to both `C:\cygwin\usr\lib\pig` and `C:\cygwin\lib\pig`, a configuration that cannot be working, for obvious reasons (at least once one understood how the cygdrive is mounted). Thus `/usr/lib/pig` did not work for me as I had only the folder `C:\cygwin\usr\lib\pig` and not the folder `C:\cygwin\lib\pig` created.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try option "-m, --mixed : like --windows, but with regular slashes (C:/WINNT)"

```
$ cd /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home
$  cygpath -m $(pwd)
C:/cygwin64/home
```